# text_field, include optional drop down menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, textfield, form-control

When a user clicks:

```
<%= f.text_field :challenge, class: 'form-control' placeholder: 'Enter Challenge' %>
```

I want a drop down menu to appear with a few options like, "Lose 10 Pounds", "Quit Smoking" or "Run a 5K".

But they would still have the option to ignore the drop down menu and type in their own challenge.

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for `chosen` or `select2`.  Not sure if this is a good question for stackoverflow, though.

Comment: Link: https://select2.github.io/. Just use that. This question isn't a rails question per se. From the point of view of Rails, you'll just have a regular text box. Then, you'll use javascript to implement the additional drop down option that you want.

Comment: Thanks @joshua.paling. I'm going to give select2 a try and report back with an answer unless you want to just give it so I can close out the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

In terms of native HTML components, understood by the browser (and generatable by rails), the only options you have are "text fields" and "drop downs". There's no such thing as a hybrid of the two.

So, that means you have to opt for a text field, and then add the additional dropdown functionality yourself. From the perspective of Rails, all you're using is a plain old text field, and you'll be adding the additional dropdown functionality in the browser, with javascript. Basically it'll be a text field, but when you click on it, it gives you a list of things, and if you click on one thing from that list, it will automatically populate the text field with that value. But, it's still "just a text field".

You're not the first to want this functionality, and there's a bunch of javascript libraries already built. Try https://select2.github.io/ to start with, or look at http://www.unheap.com/section/inputs-forms/selectboxes/ for lots more potential options.

Comment: Thanks for that perfect explanation! That's why googling can sometimes be problematic like, text_field drop down menus. "Ask the right questions if you're to find the right answers"

Comment: Yeah, it's really tricky when you don't even know what exactly you want to search for. Glad to help.